# Bootstrap nav bar menu goes out when breakpoint is changed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, containers, navbar

I changed the breakpoint for the bootstrap navbar using this code:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.navbar-text {
    float: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
/* since 3.1.0 */
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    display: block!important;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.collapsing {
    overflow: hidden!important;
}
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
}
```

My problem is that between 768px and the new breakpoint, the menu goes out of the nav container, and i want it to behave like in mobile (stay inside container and add a vertical scroll bar). I may be mising some css but no idea what :(

EDIT: Here you have the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nato522/e71e8bfd/

EDIT2: also, a picture to show the problem
[navbar issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ad6F.png)

Comment: Give also your html code

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the fiddle. It is updated now @BlackBird

Comment: Your navbar is fine. Can't find any problem. :(

Comment: @BlackBird i added a picture too so the problem can be seen. It happens only between 768px and the breakpoint (1000px)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.navbar-text {
    float: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
/* since 3.1.0 */
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    display: block!important;
    overflow-y: auto!important;
    overflow-x: hidden!important;
}
.collapsing {
    overflow: hidden!important;
}
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}}
```

Comment: This worked! so just !important did the trick then T.T
Thanks!